# How to set "next" url recieved by flask_github.authorized_handler?

Tags: python, github, flask

The example github.authorized_handler in the documentation for Github-flask looks something like this:

```py
@app.route('/github-callback')
@github.authorized_handler
def authorized(oauth_token):
    next_url = request.args.get('next') or url_for('index')

    ### blah blah blah ###

    return redirect(next_url)
```

Presumably, `next` is the url where my web-app deposits the user when the login is finished, but I can't figure out how to control what `next` is since the authorized handler is invoked as a result of calling `authorize()` and it does not appear to take `next` as a parameter.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github-flask's `authorize()` takes an optional argument `redirect_uri`, which I was able to use to forward the `next` parameter of my `github_auth_start()` to the `authorized_handler` callback.

This didn't work at first, because I was oblivious to the requirements on `redirect_uri` specified here:

https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#redirect-urls

In particular: "The redirect URL’s path must reference a subdirectory of the callback URL."

Another requirement that seems obvious now —but didn't in the midst of it— is that the URL must be an absolute URL with scheme, host and port, and `url_for()` returns a relative URL by default, so I needed to pass `_external=True`

So now, my `github_auth_start()` looks like this:

```py
@app.route('/github-auth-start', methods=["GET"])
def github_auth_start():
    next_url = request.args.get('next') or url_for('main_page')
    if current_user.is_authenticated():
        return flask_github.authorize(
            redirect_uri = url_for(
                    'github_auth_finished',
                    _external=True,
                    next=next_url))
    return abort(403)
```

And it's working at last.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to a similar problem while using the `rauth` library to implement `OAuth2Service`. The way I got around the problem was to use the session, which would be maintained during the whole OAuth dance:

On my login route:

```
@main.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():

    if request.args.get('next'):
        session['next_url'] = request.args.get('next')
```

and then on my callback route:

```
@main.route('/callback/<provider>')
def oauth_callback(provider):

    ....

    next_url = None
    if session.get('next_url'):
        next_url = session.pop('next_url')
    else:
        next_url = url_for('main.home')

    return redirect(next_url)
```